# Is there any CSS 3 property supported in IE7, by default?

Tags: cross-browser, css

Is there any CSS 3 property supported in IE7, by default? I mean is there any css 3 properties supported in IE 7 which we can use without the use of Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024.aspx) on MSDN. The list of CSS3 properties that are supported on IE7 is pretty short:

AT-RULES: @font-face

SELECTORS: namespaced, prefix, substring, suffix, general sibling

ATTRIBUTES: ruby-align, ruby-overhang, ruby-position, text-align-last (partial), text-justify, text-overflow (partial), word-break (partial), word-wrap, writing-mode, overflow-x,    overflow-y